# Use library that may not be loaded

Tags: c#, plugins

I want to create a plugin A for a software that other plugins B/C may be able to use it. Now the tricky part is that I need it to follow these rules:

- B depends on A, and it will only load if A is present.
- C uses A, but it should function if A is not present.

For B it's easy to solve, it will just throw an error since A is not present.

Now for C, how can I achieve this? I want to use be able to use A, but it shouldn't break if A is not present.

Comment: You could I'm sure achieve this with reflection. Can you be more specific about how you would want to use classes and code in `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 case - just adding dependency to A at class level of B will fail loading of class B.

To allow optional failures - wrap all calls to A into methods and try/catch around calls to those methods so JIT failures can be caught:

```
 class C
 {
   // no references to A at class level

   int MethodUsingA()
   {
      // use A here
   }

   int MethodTryingToUseA()
   {
      try 
      {
        return MethodUingA(); // will throw loader error 
                              // during JIT if A assembly is missing 
      }
      catch // use specific exception, LoaderException?
      {
        return 42; // JIT of MethodUingA failed
      }
 }
```

If you need solution for larger number of classes/methods you may instead consider reflection to load manually and provide alternative implementations if loading failed.

Comment: This actually does it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If by "library" you mean ".net assembly" then you may want to try to use AppDomain.GetAssemblies to check if the assembly is loaded ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx)) and look for your assembly in this array.

To call some methods from the assembly you may want to inspect this example
[on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39.aspx)

Comment: So you first check if you have the assembly you want and then you use reflection to execute the code from it.